# Highcharts - Change legend index order

Tags: highcharts

When creating a chart with stacked columns using highcharts my series are added by default from top to bottom - the first added series is placed on top. I'd like to alter this behaviour so that the last added series was on top. I tried to change index and zIndex options, but then items in legend got reordered as well. 
Here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/6bCBf/7/.

```
$(function () {

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            renderTo: 'container'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
             }
         },    

        series: [
            {
                name: 'base',
                data: [10, 20, 30],
                index:25,
                zIndex:10
            },
            {
                name: 'sec',
                data: [30, 20, 10],
                index:1,
                zIndex:9
            }
        ]
    });   
});
```

Is it possible to change stack order, but keep legend ordering? I'd just like to have legend ordered alphabetically, but items in chart added from bottom to top.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes that's most definitely possible.

What you are looking for is the parameter called [**`legendIndex`**](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.legendIndex).

This will allow you to specifiy the order of the items in the legend; hence being able to switch the stacked columns and not switch the legend items.

For example, you could do the following:

```
series: [
        {
            name: 'base',
            data: [10, 20, 30],
            index:1,
            legendIndex:0
        },
        {
            name: 'sec',
            data: [30, 20, 10],
            index:0,
            legendIndex:1
        }
    ]
```

## [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aezHL/)

---

### Update: sorting shared tooltip

In reaction to [Hanoncs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4941538/hanoncs) comment, it is possible to sort the order in a [shared tooltip](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared) as in the legend by using a little hack. This hack goes as follows:

1. Use the property

   ```
   yAxis: {
       reversedStacks: false 
   },
   ```
2. Reverse the `index` property of the added series. In the example above, series `'base'` then has `index:0` and `'sec'` is given `index:1`. The items in the shared tooltip will be sorted reversely.

## [**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/a0f9jdL7/)

---

Comment: Is there a way to do this same thing to order the grouped tooltip also? Its out of order in the tooltip.

Comment: @Hanoncs: Yes, that is possible. See my updated answer.

Comment: Is there a way to set the series index dynamically? For example, update series index on load or redraw based on a certain condition?. Please help if you can.

Comment: Just found this - setting the legendIndex is very useful! See e.g. https://www.coronavisualizer.org/cv_vaccs.php#chart-pct-pop-vaccinated

Comment: @RobBanmeadows Glad to hear it was helpful.

Comment: This helped me too. My setup had a Series and multiple SerieData objects inside. I alterede LegendIndex which is 0-based and could fix up so the Legend came in the natural order towards the series added reading the bar chart from top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can use index parameter which allows to control order http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.index

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it its correct way.
But using CSS also you can change the order of your legends.

In my case i have angular component legends & following HTML in it which will generate dynamically.

---

```html
<div class="legend">
    <div>legend 1</div>
    <div>legend 2</div>
    <div>legend 3</div>
</div>
```

After applying some CSS it will reverse the order of legends.

```css
:host ::ng-deep .saving-chat .legend {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```