# Highcharts: Place serie with least value on the top

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

Is there a way to place the serie(s) with the most values in the bottom and the ones with the least values on the top, so it doesn't ruin the plot?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'area'
  },
  xAxis: {
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    type: 'datetime',
    title: {
      enabled: false
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      lineColor: '#666666',
      lineWidth: 1,
      marker: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        lineColor: '#666666'
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Approved',
    color: 'green',
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 06),
      y: 21
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 07),
      y: 21
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 08),
      y: 21
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 09),
      y: 21
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 10),
      y: 21
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 11),
      y: 19
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 12),
      y: 19
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 13),
      y: 19
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 14),
      y: 19
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 15),
      y: 19
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 16),
      y: 19
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 17),
      y: 19
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 18),
      y: 19
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 19),
      y: 21
    }, ]
  }, {
    name: 'Proposal',
    color: 'yellow',
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 11),
      y: 2
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 12),
      y: 2
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 13),
      y: 2
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 14),
      y: 2
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 15),
      y: 2
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 16),
      y: 2
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 17),
      y: 2
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 18),
      y: 2
    }, ]
  }, {
    name: 'Rejected',
    color: 'grey',
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 06),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 07),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 08),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 09),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 10),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 11),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 12),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 13),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 14),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 15),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 16),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 17),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 18),
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(2017, 09, 19),
      y: 1
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/atc4sxzL/2/

Please note that the series are generated dynamically in Python through Flask.

Comment: It looks like your question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997717/highcharts-change-legend-index-order

Comment: @Calaris - problem is I don't define the order of the series. I though there was a for highcharts to check the series and sort them according to their length

Comment: Serie is not a word, series is both singular and plural

Comment: I will remember that for next time. Thanks Nova :)

Comment: @Uthman by saying "most values" and "least values" do you mean number (amount) of points in a series or how how/low these values are?

Comment: @KamilKulig number of points in a series :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made something that works, and does what you are asking. I added the following to chart.events.load:

```
var orderingArray = []
let series = this.series;
for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
  orderingArray.push({
    index: i,
    arrLen: series[i].yData.length
  })
}
orderingArray = orderingArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.arrLen - b.arrLen;
});
for (var i = 0; i < orderingArray.length; i++) {
  series[orderingArray[i]['index']].update({
    index: i + 1
  });
}
```

What is not so great about this is that I am calling `update` the same amount of times as there are series. So in this case, the chart is redrawn 3 times, which is unnecessary. But I did not find another way to do it, tried with `setOptions()` and calling `redraw()` manually, but it did not work. Just FYI.

**Working example here**: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/atc4sxzL/4/

**API on chart.events.load**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: Tihs is exactly what I have been looking for! I will also test this with drilldown and will let you know how it goes :)